# Adding a new column for substruction : Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains: `TIMESTAMP`, `P_ACT_KW` and `P_SOUSCR`.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/power.csv',delimiter=';')
```

First, I dropped missing observations:

```
df_no_missing = df2.dropna()
```

Then, I try to add a new column named `depassement` , which contains the value 0 `if(df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR']) < 0 else  df2['P_ACT_KW']- df2['P_SOUSCR']`.

```
df_no_missing['depassement'] = np.where((df_no_missing['P_SOUSCR'] - df_no_missing['P_ACT_KW']) < 0), 0, df_no_missing['P_ACT_KW'] - df_no_missing['P_SOUSCR']
```

But I get this error :

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
----> 1 df_no_missing['depassement'] = np.where((df_no_missing['P_SOUSCR'] - df_no_missing['P_ACT_KW'])  2357             self._set_item(key, value)    2358     2359     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)    2421     2422         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2423         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)    2424         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)    2425 

C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value)    2576     2577             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 2578             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)    2579             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):    2580                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)    2768     2769     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 2770         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')    2771     2772     if isinstance(data, PeriodIndex):

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Any idea please to resolve this problem?

Comment: It looks like need `df_no_missing['depassement'] = np.where((df_no_missing['P_SOUSCR'] - df_no_missing['P_ACT_KW']) < 0, 0, df_no_missing['P_ACT_KW'] - df_no_missing['P_SOUSCR'])`, end bracket was added and  one another removed.

Comment: @jezrael thank you very much, When I add the parenthese , I got this warning message : "C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':"

Comment: When you have a large traceback message, formatting it as code is better for readibility because quoting wraps the text (it is not possible to fix that later as well). Can you post the traceback wrapped in `<pre>` and `</pre>` please?

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameter `inplace=True` to `df2` for inplace removing `NaN` and correct parentheses:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'P_SOUSCR':[10,2,1,np.nan],
                    'P_ACT_KW':[4,5,6,4]})

df2.dropna(inplace=True)
print (df2)
   P_ACT_KW  P_SOUSCR
0         4      10.0
1         5       2.0
2         6       1.0

df2['depassement'] = np.where((df2['P_SOUSCR'] - df2['P_ACT_KW']) < 0,
                               0, 
                               df2['P_ACT_KW'] - df2['P_SOUSCR'])
print (df2)
   P_ACT_KW  P_SOUSCR  depassement
0         4      10.0         -6.0
1         5       2.0          0.0
2         6       1.0          0.0
```

Another solution is add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df_no_missing = df2.dropna().copy()
```